# How to Customize the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to change GridView looks according to one of my existing table using C# ASP.NET.  Actually I have a GridView which has explained below.

mission.aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
              CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero">
</asp:GridView>
```

The above GridView is generating the following HTML output.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero"
       cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" 
       id="MainContent_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Mission_vision_ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Image</th>
      <th scope="col">Description</th>
      <th scope="col">Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>hello subhra</td>
      <td>Cardiology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>fever</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>pathology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>~\Upload\002.jpg</td>
      <td>hii</td>
      <td>pathology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1.jpg</td>
      <td>haii vision</td>
      <td>vision</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I need the result table format exactly like below table.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
    <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <col class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl. No</th>
      <th>Heading</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mission</td>
      <td><img src="images/resource/me.jpg" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt...</td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Vision</td>
      <td><img src="images/resource/me.jpg" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;"></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt...</td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: GridView would not be able to generate this. You can try using jQuery here to build a custom template and populate it with your data.

Comment: @ Matt :Do you have any idea how to do this.Actually i am beginner of ASP.NET.

Comment: using a listview will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the gridview by adding `ItemTemplate` . Below is an example of how you can customize the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" ItemStyle-CssClass="someClass">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Category") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here each `TemplateField` is a `column` of your `gridview`.

You can apply `class` to `TemplateField` by using `ItemStyle-CssClass` property which will be rendered as `td`.

Here `Eval("Category")` will take the value of column "Category" from datasource by which you have binded the `gridview`.

You can also use `BoundField` which will be `td` of your table.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="items" HeaderText="Meta Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" ItemStyle-CssClass="someClass" />
```

Here `DataField="items"` is name of column of from datasource.

Comment: @ Mairaj:Inside eval what i will put.